# How can I create a method in JS like an abstract method in Java?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a small game - rock paper scissors.

I have a prototype - `RPSPlayer` and I have two kinds of players: `Player1` , `Player2` (player1 & player2 are objects with a prototype of RPSPlayer) each player plays with the function: `Player1.play()`.

Each player has a different strategy for the game. Thus, I need 2 implementations for `play()`. If it was Java, I would create an abstract class `RPSPlayer` with an abstract method `play()` and 2 other classes which inherit from `RPSPlayer`; each of them would have its own implementation for `play()`.

My question is: what is the correct way to do it in JS? I hope I made myself clear, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define an empty function on the prototype:

```
RPSPlayer.prototype.play = function() {};
```

or if you want to force an implementation of this function, you can make it throw an error:

```
RPSPlayer.prototype.play = function() {
     throw new Error('Call to abstract method play.');
};
```

This is how the [Google Closure library](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.html) is doing it, with its [`goog.abstractMethod` function](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.source.html#line412):

```
goog.abstractMethod = function() {
  throw Error('unimplemented abstract method');
};
```

which is to be used as

```
Foo.prototype.bar = goog.abstractMethod
```

Comment: but where do i implement the two different play() functions?

Comment: @rob: Well, either you assign it to each player after you created the instance `player1.play = function(){}...`, or, if `Player1` and `Player2` are actually "classes" inheriting from `RPSPlayer`, you define the functions at their prototype.